# Redshift can't convert a string to a date, tried multiple functions

Tags: sql, type-conversion, amazon-redshift, to-date

I have a table with a field called `ADATE`, it is a `VARCHAR(16)` and the values are like so: `2019-10-22-09:00`.

I am trying to convert this do a `DATE` type but cannot get this to work.

I have tried:

**1**

```
TO_DATE(ADATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

> Can't cast database type date to string

**2**

```
TO_DATE(LEFT(ADATE, 10), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

> Can't cast database type date to string

**3**

```
TO_DATE(TRUNC(ADATE), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

> XX000: Invalid digit, Value '-', Pos 4, Type: Decimal

**4**

```
CAST(ADATE AS DATE)
```

> Error converting text to date

**5**

```
CAST(LEFT(ADATE, 10) AS DATE)
```

> Error converting text to date

**6**

```
CAST(TRUNC(ADATE) AS DATE)
```

> Error converting numeric to date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was the data containing blanks (not Nulls) so the error was around them.

I resolved this by using the following code:

TO_DATE(LEFT(CASE WHEN adate = '' THEN NULL ELSE adate END, 10), 'YYYY-MM-DD') adate

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, you have bad date string values -- which is why the value should be stored as a date to begin with.

I don't think Redshift has a way of validating the date before attempting the comparison, or of avoiding an error.  But you can use `case` and regular expressions to see if the value is reasonable.  This might help:

```
(case when left(adate, 10) ~ '^(19|20)[0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]$'
      then to_date(left(adate, 10), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
 end)
```

This is not precise . . . you can make it more complex so month 19 is not permitted (for instance), but it is likely to catch the errors.

Comment: This gives every field as a `NULL`.

Comment: @Matt . . . I missed the last three characters.  This uses `left()` to only consider the date portion of the string.

Comment: Shouldn't the reg ex be: '^(19|20)[0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]$' ... the day can be anywhere from 1-31 so i assume it should be [0-3][[0-9]?