# Converting TRY_PARSE and timezone to date from SQL Server to AWS redshift

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 questions:

**Question #1**: how can I rewrite `TRY_PARSE` function from SQL Server to AWS Redshift?

I have T-SQL code like this:

```
SELECT 
    ORDER_ID, NAME, TRY_PARSE(VALUE AS DATE USING 'en-gb') AS Value
FROM 
    Stg_tci_INV_ORDER_ATTR  /*inv_order_attr*/
WHERE 
    name = 'MATCHED_DATE'
```

`Value` is the date column, the result will be datetime like dd/MM/YYYY character type.

I used the `TRY_PARSE` function to convert into date type `YYYY-MM-DD`. I converted it to AWS Redshift using the `TO_DATE` function, but it didn't work. How can I do that?

**Question #2**: is there any function to convert timezone type to date type?

```
SELECT 
    order_id, name, 
    CONVERT(date, SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset,VALUE), DATENAME(TzOffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()))) AS value
FROM 
    staging.stg_tci_inv_order_attr /*inv_order_attr*/
WHERE 
    LOWER(name) = 'transferred_date'
```

This code will return a datetime like

```
2020-03-06T10:07:36.041Z
```

What's the function can be use to convert this data type into `YYYY-MM-DD` type?

Thank you

Comment: Are you asking about Redshift or SQL Server here? The above is valid T-SQL.

Comment: Side question: Why are you using `LOWER(name) = 'transferred_date'` in your `WHERE`? If you are using a case insensitive collation, then the `LOWER` is only going to serve to make the query non-SARGable and perform poorly. If, however, you are using a case sensitive collation, then you have defined that a value like `'transferred_date'` and `'Transferred_Date'` should be treated as different values. Either you should be ensuring the values stored in the table have consistent cases or you should have a (`PERSISTED`) computed column with the value in lower case, that can be indexed.

Comment: The rule is one post, one question. This is to avoid the inevitable confusion resulting for mixing questions, comments, and replies for two different issues within the same thread.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redshift can't convert a string to a date, tried multiple functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61541152/redshift-cant-convert-a-string-to-a-date-tried-multiple-functions)